# Where condition based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I want to select all entries from a table where MEMBER_STATUS = 2. However, this status can change over time. Each time the member status changed the old entry is saved in another table called ADRESS_history.

```
ADDRESS (each ID only exists once)
ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | MEMBER_STATUS | DTM
1  | Tom       | Mueller  | 2             | 2016-04-02
2  | John      | Doe      | 2             | 2016-03-02
3  | David     | Allen    | 4             | 2016-04-04
4  | Neil      | Fiore    | 8             | 2016-04-04

ADDRESS_history (IDs can have multiple entries)
ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | MEMBER_STATUS | DTM
2  | John      | Doe      | 2             | 2012-02-02
3  | David     | Allen    | 2             | 2013-03-01
1  | Tom       | Mueller  | 1             | 2015-03-30
2  | John      | Doe      | 2             | 2015-08-22
1  | Tom       | Mueller  | 4             | 2012-02-02
1  | Tom       | Mueller  | 3             | 2013-02-02
```

When the last change in the ADDRESS table took place after 2016-04-01, I would like to use the member status of the most recent entry for the user in the TABLE ADDRESS_history. When the last change in the ADDRESS table took place before 2016-04-01, I would like to use the member status of the entry from the ADDRESS table. How can alter this query to reflect this?

```
select *
from ADDRESS a
join ADDRESS_history using (ID)
MEMBER_STATUS = 2
```

The result should be

```
ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | MEMBER_STATUS | DTM
1  | Tom       | Mueller  | 1             | 2015-03-30
2  | John      | Doe      | 2             | 2016-03-02
3  | David     | Allen    | 2             | 2013-03-01
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from here.

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.firstname
     , a.lastname
     , if( a.dtm >= '2016-04-01'
         , ( SELECT ah.member_status
               FROM address_history ah
               WHERE ah.id = a.id
                 AND ah.dtm = t.dtm
           )
         , a.member_status
         ) member_status
     , if( a.dtm >= '2016-04-01'
         , t.dtm
         , a.dtm
         ) dtm
  FROM address a
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT id, max(dtm) dtm
                  FROM address_history
                  WHERE dtm < '2016-04-01'
                  GROUP BY id
              ) t
      ON t.id = a.id
  WHERE a.member_status = 2
    OR t.id is not null
```